# if it was a random.random() with a seed, I could figure it out because the output will always be the same. if there a similar solution for this?

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

```
def rand_range(rng):
    return rng - (secrets.randbits(4) % rng)
```

```
rand_suit = rand_range(4)
```

the `rng` value is 4. is there any way to find out the rand_suit?

Comment: where is `secrets` defined please ?

Comment: Secrets is added as a module. ```import secrets```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to find it out. `rand_suit` can only take on 4 possible values, 4, 3, 2, and 1. So just try them all and see which one works.

Comment: Correct, but the application gives me only one chance to try and when I get it wrong, it generates a new random and asks me again. I want to find a way to get it right everytime